# Here's an idea: a "Vote up" button for the web (like the Facebook "like" button)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes browsing the web for the answer to a problem, I found a blog post that explains and solve the problem. If the blog post or article is good and **I felt like I should "vote up"** even when I'm not at Stackoverflow.

So, my idea is that you implement a **"Vote Up"** button that people can place in their blog posts or articles, and people can vote.

The results could end in a Board in the new programmers.se site or bring some karma to the author (you surely can work out the details)

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Congratulations, you've reinvented Digg.

Comment: @Powerlord: well, yes, in the same way StackOverflow reinvented phpBB. Ahh ... and you don't need to be harsh, just try for one day.

Comment: Jeff's constant attacks on phpBB are another thing that annoys me.  The StackExchange system is so terrible at holding conversations that the SE team invented their own phpBB (well... online forum) clone.  You can find it by clicking the "chat" button on meta.

Comment: @Powerlord Isn't that because Stack Exchange isn't supposed to be for holding conversations?

Comment: @Grace Note: Right, but phpBB is supposed to be for holding conversations.  Each has their own strengths and weaknesses, but Jeff dismisses phpBB out of hand.

Answer (score 5):

I like this, but I propose a

**this totally sucked**

Button, instead. Our honesty will be our competitive advantage!

Comment: Sheesh. Plagiarism. http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/169977

Comment: Careful what you wish for, Jeff.  I might have to direct some crypto geeks over to that rainbow table blog entry...

Answer (score 2):

Basically I like this idea and shared that wish before (even when just reading the news!), but I guess this is not really SO inc.'s business. Maybe someone wants to do that as a separate project?

Answer (score 2):

SO "reinvented phpBB" by taking the core idea behind tech self-help forums (getting useful answers to questions) and making it into something that is different *and* better.

Could you explain how this idea would be different/better than Digg/Facebook/Reddit/StumbleUpon/whoever's "I like this page(|'s content|'s neat fade-in onload effect|'s whatever)", apart from "it's the SO people implementing the feature, so it'll be a Good Thing"?

I'm honestly curious, maybe you're on to something, maybe not - could you elaborate? So far, I see a Digg button with a SO look. How is it better?

Comment: Well, I'm not thinking about promoting a web page, like Digg does. Something much more simple as bringing some kind of karma to the author. I've never pushed any Digg or Reddit button, and Facebook is for friends and family. Somehow I would like to vote up some content in the web and I think the SO people can do something awesome about it.

Comment: @Eduardo Molteni: What kind of karma? If you mean "5 people like Piskvor's pages, namely this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64733/heres-an-idea-a-vote-up-button-for-the-web-like-the-facebook-like-button/64745#64745", then I don't see a difference from Digg.

Comment: Points or badges in SO or in programmers.se

Answer (score 0):

I like this idea but I honestly can't see how it work for SO.

In order for this to work you would have to display the question & all of the answers.  Isn't the whole idea of voting questions/answers up is that the **best** answer ends up with the most votes and is accepted.  (I know that is not *always* the case but as a general rule)

If you only display your answer (and presumbly the question otherwise people aren't going to know the context) then there is nothing else to compare it too.  You cant say "vote my answer up because it's the best" if you aren't going to display the other answers.

Maybe I've got the wrong end of the stick but my these are my initial thoughts.

Comment: No, no, it's not for questions and answers, it's for other programmers related post or pages around the web.

Comment: @EduardoMolteni - So what happens with the up vote?  Does it add to their reputation? Is there a new separate "blog" reputation? Or is it simply saying the x amount of users on StackOverflow think this is a good blog post etc.

Comment: Yes, something like that. I have nothing against adding to the main reputation, so people that don't have the time to answer questions, but have great tutorials or blog posts (think http://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman) can gain reputation out SO.

Comment: But having a separate "blog" reputation can work too.

Answer (score 0):

StumbleUpon has an "I like it!" and downvote button... you can submit reviews of the site if they haven't been submitted previously to SU before as well.